# Insert records from Arduino / Esp8622 to MS SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, arduino

I would like to use arduino or esp to do a data saving in the ms sql database. is it possible to do it directly? Unfortunately, I can't find any help on this subject anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no SQL Libraries written for Arduino or ESP8622. What you can do is write a REST API which does the CRUD operations on the MS SQL Database and call the REST Endpoints using the Arduino and ESP8622.

Comment: FYI: there is this: https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino. Never tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/mysql-connector-arduino/). I found it by googling "library to connect an arduino directly to a mysql server".